# How to programmatically retrieve google results?

Tags: java

Now that the Google search API has been discontinued - what is the best way to retrieve search results programmatically?

I need to get a list of files that have been indexed by google in my web site, so that I can write a script using that data.

What I want to do is delete everything cached under http://mysite.com/mypdfs/

i.e.
search for "site:mysite.com/mypdfs", 
to get back a list of pdfs on mysite.com:
    http://mysite.com/pdf/1.pdf
    http://mysite.com/pdf/1.pdf
    ...
    http://mysite.com/pdf/1000000.pdf
etc

Then use WebDriver to push them through the webmaster removal tool.

Happy to pay for the privilege if required...

Comment: Are you talking about a search engine for your own site?  Can you be more specific?

Comment: I simply want to get a list of files that have been indexed by google (matching a specific search string), so I can use it in a script

Comment: But only files that have been indexed on YOUR site?

Comment: Yes, it is to fix this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956351/how-to-remove-thousands-of-urls-from-google-cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to setup a Custom Search and use the new [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview). It's similar to the old deprecated search API and does JSON or Atoms.